# Sentence containing my vs the

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

I have two sentences to comprehend correctly.

Do you say

1. Today is an opportunity to finish off my goal.
2. Today is my opportunity to finish off my goal.

Comment: It depends what you mean. (1) suggests that you will have several opportunities to finish the work, today being one of them. (2) suggests that today there will be an opportunity special to you, perhaps the only one you will get.

Comment: The second can imply that it's your only chance, the first does not.  The first may also be used when you are acting in a group interest, or talking about someone else, whereas the second is personal and singular.